# Wi-Fi opt-out Microsoft & Google

Tags: wireless-networking, privacy, wifi-configuration, ssid

So if I want to opt out Google's WiFi Assistant I have to add

```
_nomap
```

to my SSID.

If I want to opt out from Microsoft's WiFi Sense I have to add

```
_optout
```

to my SSID.

What if I want to opt out both?
Can I combine them?

```
SSID_nomap_optout?

SSID_optout_nomap?

SSID_nomap _optout?

SSID_optout _nomap?
```

What a trouble...

Answer (score 16):

Google's `_nomap` must appear at the end of the SSID while the Windows `_optout` can be anywhere in the SSID, so this *should* work based on the docs below:

```
SSID_optout_nomap
```

---

https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10-open-wi-fi-hotspots:

> ...you can opt your network out by including `_optout` somewhere in the Wi-Fi network name (also called the SSID). For example, `mynetwork_optout` or `my_optout_network`. When you do this, Windows won’t automatically connect people to your open network.

---

https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/1725632:

> To opt out, change the SSID (name) of your Wi-Fi access point (your wireless network name) so that it ends with `_nomap`. For example, if your SSID is `12345`, you would change it to `12345_nomap`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use SSID_nomap_optout.

Source: http://krebsonsecurity.com/2015/07/windows-10-shares-your-wi-fi-with-contacts/

Comment: "The Register seems to think Windows 10 upgraders can avoid each by including both “_nomap” and “_optout” in the Wi-Fi network name, but this article at How-To Geek says users will need to choose the lesser of two evils."

So can I combine both or not? Couldn't understand that well.

Comment: Google and Microsoft opt-out are independent of each other.  The register is a horrible source for technology facts, or any facts, for that matter

Comment: @ThisDisaster what article?

Comment: This contradicts the [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1202168/774713) and apparently *"Google's `_nomap` must appear at the end"*...?